# Cant rollback a migration. StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I just migrated a file but in the def down I forgot to place the columns in reverse order. the schema was updated after migration but i cant rollback. I tried reversing the column orders in the migration file.

```
class AddAttachmentPictureToHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    change_table :hotels do |t|
      t.attachment :picture
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      t.float :distance
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :hotels, :picture
    remove_float :hotels, :latitude
    remove_float :hotels, :longitude
    remove_float :hotels, :distance
  end
end
```

My schema is this

```
  create_table "hotels", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "city_id"
    t.string "picture_file_name"
    t.string "picture_content_type"
    t.integer "picture_file_size"
    t.datetime "picture_updated_at"
    t.float "lattitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.float "distance"
    t.index ["city_id"], name: "index_hotels_on_city_id"
  end
```

How can i rollback it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this

```
  def self.down
    remove_column :hotels, :picture
    remove_column :hotels, :lattitude
    remove_column :hotels, :longitude
    remove_column :hotels, :distance
    remove_column :hotels, :picture_file_name
    remove_column :hotels, :picture_content_type
  end
```

On a side note `lattitude` is misspelled and should be `latitude`

Comment: ya my bad, i did rake db:drop db:create db:migrate, after removing the columns from migration file, worked fine. But thanks